# py.test is not showing any "print" output even with flag "-s"

Tags: python, pytest

On Ubuntu 20.04.5 using pytest 7.2.0 with python 3.8.10 I have a test script which is run by

```
py.test -s /path/to/script ...
```

but it does not show any output of `print` statements. When running it with

```
py.test -v -s /path/to/script ...
```

I double checked that the test case I am working on is actually executed - but still no print output.

What could be going on?